# How to create a temporary table in MySql from C# datatable?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a project in which i get some data from a remote server and stores in datatable using C#

```
 DataTable source_db_table;
        public void fetch_from_source_db_table(bool verbose, string machine, string table_name, string time_from, string time_to)
        {
            string query =$"SELECT {table_name}.*  " +
    $"FROM {table_name} " +
    $"WHERE  {table_name}" +
    $".u_time >='{time_from}' " +
    $"AND u_time <=  '{time_to}' " +
    $"AND mac_id = '{machine}' OR mac_id = 0;";
            source_db_table = select_db2(verbose, query);
```

now I want to use that "datatable" to create a temporary table in MySql . I have searched alot on internet but didnt find anything.

Comment: _"A temporary table in MySQL is created by using CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statement"_ - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/

Comment: I want to create a temporary table from the datatable

Comment: Well isn't that just `INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE VALUES {from datatable}`?

Comment: Values against which columns ? how can i specify columns from datatable?

Comment: Datatable column names changes every time as it fetch results from different tables

Comment: Do you need the intermediate stage? Otherwise you could do `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE SELECT … FROM …` and then pull that into the datatable. Or don't do `SELECT *`.

Comment: i didnt understand you completely can you give brief explaination

Comment: `string query =$"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE_{table_name} SELECT {table_name}.*  FROM {table_name} WHERE  {table_name} {etc}" ` then select from TEMP_TABLE_{table_name} into a datatable?

Comment: i think so you didnt get my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
    StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("create temporary table tablename(");
    foreach (var Col in source_db_table .Columns)
    {
      sCommand.Append("`"+Col+"`" + " varchar(200), ");
    }
    sCommand.Append(");");
    string scmd = ReplaceLastOccurrence(sCommand.ToString(), ",", "");
```

in this way your temporary table would be created and now you will just insert rows into this.